# Destroyed text in sudo dialog

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dialog

I used the application "HDD Cleaner" to clear up my ~/Library/Cache folder. After this action I see the following dialog, whenever OS X asks for my sudo rights:

[image: img]

It's the only dialog that has this appearance. How can I restore the default dialog? I already switched the languages and region, but without success.

I'm using 10.10.1 on my MacBook Air Early 2014.

Comment: Did you reboot after cleaning the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible it could have messed up the Font cache.  Restart into Safe mode, (hold down shift after the boot chime) and release Shift when the grey screen and Apple logo appear.  When asked to log in, type in your password, then HOLD SHIFT and hit enter.  Reboot into OS X as normal and try again.

Hopefully it didn't delete a system font on accident.  Next, open Font Book, select all the fonts and choose Validate Fonts from the File menu.  Resolve any conflicts that it finds.  If you don't have a lot of non-standard fonts installed, you can choose Restore Standard Fonts from the File menu and reboot.  Hopefully it's something simple.

Comment: Thank you! The shutdown dialog in safe mode had the same appearance, but it's not the case in the normal mode.